# On Laplacian spectrum of Graph

Tags: graph-laplacian

can somebody refer me the article/source in which it has been proved that $G:=K_1\vee (mK_n)$ is determined by its Laplacian spectrum

Answer (score 0):

Rather Laplacian spectrum of join of any two graphs is completely determined by the Laplacian spectra of the constituting graphs.

> R. Merris, Laplacian graph eigenvectors, *Linear Algebra and its Applications*, 278 (1998), 221--236.

See Theorem 2.1, Page number 225.

Comment: in my understanding, this theorem is telling us about the eigenvalue of the join of two graphs,(and he didn`t show all those graphs with same Laplacian spectra must be isomorphic ).

Comment: @محمد عتیق طا ہر Are you asking about spectral characterization?

Comment: I need to know all those graphs which have same Laplacian eigenvalues as  $K_1 \vee (m K_n) $ and they are isomorphic or not.